# How to do a postgres textsearch with large amounts of text as query parameter?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I have a "trademarks" table like this:

```sql
create table
  public.trademarks (
    id bigint generated always as identity,
    owner_id text null,
    trademark text null,
    constraint trademarks_pkey primary key (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

My goal is to pass a text to a query and get all trademarks that the text contains. For example passing:

> Walt Disney was an American entrepreneur, animator, and film producer
> who became one of the most influential figures in the entertainment
> industry. He co-founded the Disney Brothers Studio, which later became
> The Walt Disney Company, and created beloved characters such as Mickey
> Mouse and Donald Duck. Through his innovative and enduring works,
> Disney left an indelible mark on the world of animation, theme parks,
> and television, capturing the imagination of audiences for
> generations.

Should return the rows with "Walt Disney", "Mickey Mouse", "Donald Duck". etc.

I came up with this solution which works, but I wanted to hear some expert opinions on this problem:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  trademarks
WHERE
'Walt Disney was an American entrepreneur, animator, and film producer who became one of the most influential figures in the entertainment industry. He co-founded the Disney Brothers Studio, which later became The Walt Disney Company, and created beloved characters such as Mickey Mouse and Donald Duck. Through his innovative and enduring works, Disney left an indelible mark on the world of animation, theme parks, and television, capturing the imagination of audiences for generations.' ILIKE '%' || trademark || '%';
```

Comment: Well if `trademark` is a single item then you will only get a return for that item, If `trademark` is a string with multiple items you most likely get nothing.

Comment: Yes, `trademark` is a single item

Comment: What if the supplied text contains punctuation or symbols which interrupt the trademark?  Or misspellings? Are you concerned about performance?

Comment: As long as the supplied text contains words that make a trademark, I need to return them. Punctuation or symbols don't matter. Yes, I am very concerned about performance. The database will contain millions of entries.

Comment: It also doesn't matter if the first word of a trademark is at the beginning of the text and the second word of the trademark is at the end. I would still like to return the trademark if possible

Answer (score 1):

My understanding:

1. You have a table with millions of records.
2. This table has a column named 'trademarks'.
3. This column contains values like 'Donald Dock', 'Mickey Mouse', 'Walt Disney', and millions of other values.
4. Your input is a chunk of text that may have multiple trademark occurrences within the text, which are present in 4 above.
5. You want to find all the trademarks that are in 4 as well as in 5.
6. The problem is that if the input text, for example, is "Walt Disney was an American entrepreneur", then you will have to search the DB for "Walt Disney", Disney was", "was an", "Was an American" .... lots of combinations. For example, if the longest trademark has 5 words, then you will have to take all 5 continuous 5 word occurrences in the input text and match all of them against the millions of existing trademarks in the table

This does not sound advisable to do it directly in the DB.

- You could probably create a read-only view that contains the
  trademarks in sorted order.
- Then write a stored procedure / function
  to
- take in the input text
- break it into chunks
- take combinations from each chunk
- Match each of the combinations against the view
- Round out the search by taking each chunk and taking combinations that cross a chunk's boundary

But for a real life maintainable solution,I think you will / should do it in the application layer - by using a tree-based model and parallelization of the searches involved

Answer (score 1):

Create a Full-Text Search Index:

First, you need to create a full-text search index on the column you want to search within. Let's assume you have a table named documents with a content column that contains the long text data. Here's how you can create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX trademark_search_idx ON trademarks USING gin(to_tsvector('english', trademark));
```

(This index uses the to_tsvector function to convert the text data into a format optimized for full-text searching.)

Perform Full-Text Searches:

```
    SELECT * FROM documents WHERE to_tsvector('english', content) @@ to_tsquery('english', 
'Walt Disney was an American entrepreneur, animator, and film producer who became one of the most influential figures in the entertainment industry. He co-founded the Disney Brothers Studio, which later became The Walt Disney Company, and created beloved characters such as Mickey Mouse and Donald Duck. Through his innovative and enduring works, Disney left an indelible mark on the world of animation, theme parks, and television, capturing the imagination of audiences for generations.'
);
```

This query uses the @@ operator to match the text in the content column against the tsquery created from the search term.

To Optimize Performance further:

When dealing with a large number of records, you can further optimize performance by using features like pagination (LIMIT and OFFSET) to retrieve results in smaller chunks like:

```
    SELECT * FROM documents
    WHERE to_tsvector('english', content) @@ to_tsquery('english', 
'Walt Disney was an American entrepreneur, animator, and film producer who became one of the most influential figures in the entertainment industry. He co-founded the Disney Brothers Studio, which later became The Walt Disney Company, and created beloved characters such as Mickey Mouse and Donald Duck. Through his innovative and enduring works, Disney left an indelible mark on the world of animation, theme parks, and television, capturing the imagination of audiences for generations.'
)
    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Additionally, consider using tools like caching and indexing strategies to speed up queries even further.

Remember that full-text search is a powerful tool, but its performance depends on various factors, including the complexity of the search, the amount of data, and the server's resources. It's also a good practice to regularly analyze and monitor the performance of your queries to ensure they remain efficient as your data grows.

Answer (score 1):

This query helps us find trademarks that have all their words present in a given text. We break down the trademarks and text into words, compare them, and get the trademarks that match our criteria.
I also saw your post on up work.

```
-- Step 1: Create a table named "trademarks" to hold trademark information
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.trademarks;
CREATE TABLE public.trademarks (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, -- Unique identifier for each trademark
  owner_id TEXT NULL,      -- Owner's identification (can be empty)
  trademark TEXT NULL       -- The actual trademark text (can be empty)
);

-- Step 2: Add some example trademark data into the "trademarks" table
INSERT INTO public.trademarks (owner_id, trademark) VALUES
  ('1', 'disney Walt The'),                  
  ('2', 'Mickey Mouse'),                
  ('3', 'Donald Duck'),                 
  ('4', 'The Walt Disney Company'),     
  ('5', 'ddd');            

-- Example provided text
WITH provided_text AS (
  SELECT 'Walt sds Disney was an American entrepreneur, animator, and film producer who became one of the most influential
  figures in the entertainment industry. He co-founded the Disney Brothers Studio, which later became The Walt Disney sds Company, 
  and created beloved characters such as Mickey Mouse and Donald Duck. Through his innovative and enduring works,
  Disney left an indelible mark on the world of animation, theme parks, and television, capturing the imagination of audiences for generations.' AS text
),
-- Split trademark words into separate rows
trademark_words AS (
  SELECT ID, unnest(string_to_array(trademark, ' ')) AS word
  FROM public.trademarks
)
-- Convert the provided text into separate words
, text_words AS (
  SELECT unnest(string_to_array(text, ' ')) AS word
  FROM provided_text
)
-- Check if all trademark words are present in the text
, matched_trademarks AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT tw.id
  FROM trademark_words tw
  LEFT JOIN text_words tw2 ON tw2.word = tw.word
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM trademark_words
    WHERE tw2.word IS NULL
  )
)
-- Retrieve trademark records based on matched IDs
SELECT t.*
FROM public.trademarks t
JOIN matched_trademarks mt ON t.id = mt.id;
```

Breakdown of the CTEs

Provided Text: We have a piece of text that talks about different things. We'll give it a name "provided_text" so we can work with it easily.

Splitting Trademark Words: We're looking at our trademarks and splitting them into separate words. For each trademark, we'll list its ID and the words that make it up. This helps us handle trademarks more effectively.

Converting Text Words: Similar to how we handled trademarks, we're breaking down the provided text into individual words. This makes it simpler to work with the text.

Checking Trademark Match: We're checking if all the words that make up our trademarks are found in the provided text. We're creating a list of IDs of trademarks that match this condition.

Getting Matching Trademarks: Using the list of matching trademark IDs, we're getting the complete trademark records that meet the condition of having all their words in the text.

**Please note adding tv_sector would change Company to compani and mouse to mous which may lead to an error.**